# How to include third party libraries in C++ windows?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I have the boost library in my downloads folders. When I tried to include a particular file. It is throwing errors. Below is the code and the steps I did.

\main.cpp

```
#include "type_index.hpp"

int main(){
//some code
return 0;
}
```

I opened the command prompt and ran the following command

```
g++ -IC:\Users\Owner\Downloads\boost_1_70_0\boost -o main main.cpp
```

I got the following error in command prompt

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\boost_1_70_0\boost/type_index.hpp:17:28: fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/config.hpp>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
```

How can I run the above file? Do I have to change the location of boost directory from downloads folder to some where within `mingw` directories?

Adding the picture of directory:
[image]

Comment: What is the contents of `C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\boost_1_70_0\boost`? Is there a sub-directory named `boost`?

Comment: yes. I will include the pic of the directory

Comment: That directory for amending to the include path should be `-IC:\Users\Owner\Downloads\boost_1_70_0` . All the boost headers look for the boost root as part of their specified file name. Likewise, your source shoud do the same, and thus your source is wrong. it should say `#include <boost/type_index.hpp>`. Fix your include path, preface all *your* source file references to boost headers with `boost/`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: And related, that pic now-posted is **not** the directory @Someprogrammerdude asked about. He specifically asked what the content of `C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\boost_1_70_0\boost` was; you showed the content of `C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\boost_1_70_0`. There's a reason he asked, and it directly relates to my prior comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks its working. For future c/c++ beginners it will be helpful if you "answer it". And I will mark it is as a answer.

Comment: @Samer before I answer it, I always search for duplicates. As long as SO has been on the airwaves, nearly *all* configuration-related question are duplicates in one form or another at this point.And frankly, as long as boost has been around, and as used as it is, i'll be shocked if I can't find a duplicate for how to configure your include paths to use a boost distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `boost` is correctly configured and built on your system, there will be a location where the hub of the boost include root is located. Ex: if you downloaded and built boost in `c:\Stuff\boost_1_70_0`, then within that folder will be the hub of the boost include set, `c:\Stuff\boost_1_70_0\boost`, and it contains all of the boost headers.

boost is referenced by amending the include path to provide access to the boost include hub; **not** to provide access to the top-most headers *in* the hub. Similar to openssl, boost prefaces all of their header includes in their *own* headers, with `boost/`. The consumers of boost should do the same, Therefore, the include path must include the folder where the `boost/` hub can be found. It should **not** include the `boost/` hub itself as part of the path.

Ex: This is correct

```
g++ -Ic:\Stuff\boost_1_70_0 -o main main.cpp
```

This, on the other hand is wrong:

```
g++ -Ic:\Stuff\boost_1_70_0\boost -o main main.cpp
```

With the former, when code includes:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

the include path is searched, and the file is found. Further, within that header, when the compiler see this:

```
#include <boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp>
```

it can still resolve correctly, because dropping that "thing" on the end of one of the folders in the include path works.

Now, consider the wrong case. What happens if you configure the include path to accidentally specify the `boost/`root hub itself? Well, now *you* can do this:

```
#include <asio.hpp>
```

But as soon as the preprocessor starts in on that header it will see:

```
#include <boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp>
```

Um.. woops. The pre-processor will look for this and never find it

**Summary**

When using boost headers in your source, you always refer to them with the boost hub preamble:

```
#include <boost/headername.hpp>
```

and always include the folder where the `boost/` hub is located in your build configuration as an amended include path; *not* full path including the `boost/` hub.

Comment: Hi, hanks for the answer and Sorry for being ignorant.. What is meaning of "configured and built"?